# Unity Container for dependency injection throws exceptions, but Web API still works

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I'm building a very small web API using .NET Framework 4.5.2. In Visual Studio, I started the project as Empty, with references for Web API 2. I wanted to make use of Dependency Injection, so I did everything as explained in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection#dependency-resolution-with-the-unity-container) by Microsoft and included Unity in my project. **Everything works**, the **API acts as intended** and sends the expected responses, however... In the Visual Studio *Output* tab, I noticed many exceptions being silently raised ("Eccezione generata" means "Exception raised") right after starting the API:
[image: Silent exceptions raised by Unity]
This bugs me quite a bit. I'm concerned about the API stability and reliability. Following is the code involved in the DI process.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // As explained in the tutorial
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IDecrypter, Decrypter>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        // Routing follows...
    }
}
```

The *Decrypter* used for internal cryptography.

```
public interface IDecrypter
{
    string Decrypt(string input);
}

public class Decrypter : IDecrypter
{
    public string Decrypt(string input) { /* ... */ } 
}
```

The *Repository* used to access the database.

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    // Interface Methods...
}

public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    private readonly IDecrypter Decrypter;

    public BaseRepository(IDecrypter decrypter)
    {
        Decrypter = decrypter;
        // More code...
    }

    // More code...
}

public class MyRepository : BaseRepository, IMyRepository
{
    public MyRepository(IDecrypter decrypter) : base(decrypter)
    { }

    // Implementations of the interface methods...
}
```

The API one and only Controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyRepository myRepository;

    public MyController(IMyRepository _myRepository)
    {
        myRepository = _myRepository;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: The errors are most likely being consumed within the resolver as shown in the source code https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.IoC.Unity/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.IoC.Unity/UnityResolver.cs

Comment: @Nkosi Right, I see the code catches `ResolutionFailedException`, but what about `InvalidOperationException`? Should I be worried?

Comment: @StackLloyd I have done the same thing. But It did not work. Did you find any solution?